# Problema de retorno none no python

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um exercício no Python e não entendo por que o output tá voltando com none junto, Agradeço

```
def main(x,nomePlaneta) :
  if nomePlaneta == "Terra" : 
    valordois =  x//86400
    valortres = (x%86400)//3600
    valorquatro = ((x%86400)%3600)//60
    valorcinco = ((x%86400)%3600)%60

  elif nomePlaneta == "Jupiter":
    valordois =  x//35760
    valortres = (x%35760)//3600
    valorquatro = ((x%35760)%3600)//60
    valorcinco =  ((x%35760)%3600)%60
  elif nomePlaneta == "Venus" :
    valordois =  x//20995200
    valortres = (x% 20995200)// 3600
    valorquatro = ((x% 20995200)% 3600)//60
    valorcinco = ((x% 20995200)% 3600)%60  
  elif nomePlaneta == "Mercurio" :
    valordois =  x// 5068800
    valortres = (x%  5068800)// 3600
    valorquatro = ((x% 5068800)%  3600)//60
    valorcinco = ((x% 5068800)%  3600)%60

  print(x, 'segundos no planeta Terra equivalem a:')
  print(valordois, 'dias,',valortres, 'horas,',valorquatro, 'minutos e',valorcinco ,'segundos')

lista = input().split()

valor1 = int(lista[0])
nomePlaneta = str(lista[1])

print(main(valor1,nomePlaneta))
```

Comment: Resolvido, havia pesquisado e encontrei em alguns problemas similares, que isso acontece quando você chama a própria função dentro da função. No caso estava colocando print dentro de print. Para resolver apenas modifiquei a ultima linha   print(main(valor1,nomePlaneta)) só por main(valor1,nomePlaneta) e ai ficou correto

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade você estava imprimindo o retorno da função `main()` (o `print(main(...))`), porém esta função escreve diversas coisas mas retorna valor algum. Não há um `return` no final passando valores para quem a chamou, mas como ela finalizou sem erros ela volta o `None` (o padrão no Python).